# Issue With "Do In Groups of" In Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code to display posts in groups of 3 across the page:

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
 <% @feed_items.in_groups_of(3).each do |feeds| %>
   <div class="row">
     <% feeds.each do |feed| %>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <ol class="posts">
          <%= render feed %>
        </ol>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

It works fine if there are a number of posts that is evenly divisible by 3, however anything not (like 10 posts for example) generates the error "'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path."

Essentially I just want to display my posts so they look like:

```
    Post 1        Post 2         Post 3
    Post 4        Post 5
```

Is there a way to do this with my current code or can someone suggest a non Ruby way of doing this, for example SCSS.

Thanks!

Comment: Adding the argument 'false' to @feed_items.in_groups_of(3) fixed it. So code now reads @feed_items.in_groups_of(3, false). This removed the nil values.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap, Zurb Foundation or some other grid?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#compact`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact-21) to remove the nil values:

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
 <% @feed_items.in_groups_of(3).each do |feeds| %>
   <div class="row">
     <% feeds.compact.each do |feed| %>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <ol class="posts">
          <%= render feed %>
        </ol>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```